# How to construct an algebra / field that is infinitely countable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is well-known that a $\sigma$-algebra / $\sigma$-field can only be finite or uncountable infinite, but how to construct an example of algebra / field that is infinitely countable? This is actually a question from Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* problem 2.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is the collection of finite unions of intervals in $\Bbb{R}$ with end points in $\Bbb{Q}\cup \{\infty, -\infty\}$.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

The set of all finite and cofinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ is another example.

Comment: Got it. Many thanks!